# Issues printing numbers from web-page with selenium bot

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get all the numbers from an online listing site with selenium using python. It is meant to click on all the links and print out the numbers. Everything works perfectly except the part where it is meant to collect the phone numbers. It only prints the first number and keeps looping through the remaining ads without printing the other numbers. I suspect the issues has to do with the try statement block.

```
for ad_href in ad_hrefs:
        driver.get(ad_href)
        call = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="container"]/main/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/section/section/div/button[2]""")
        call.click()
        time.sleep(1)

        try :
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="container"]/main/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/button""").click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue

        number = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="container"]/main/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/section/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/a""")
        print(number.text)
```

Comment: would be helpful to share the site or html that it is going through as well as the output you get currently.  You want to provide as much info as possible...